# Lenis smooth scroll preventing Next Links default behaviour of scrolling to top of page on route change

Tags: next.js, smooth-scrolling

I am building a Next app where I have implemented smooth scrolling with Lenis. Everything is working perfectly apart from when you navigate between pages using nexts link element. The scroll position just remains where it was before the route change instead of the default behaviour of linking to the top of the page. If I remove Lenis then it works properly so it must be that which is causing the issue.

Has anyone else ran into this problem and know a work around for it?

The code snippet below shows how I have set up Lenis in my _app.js file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(() => {
    const lenis = new Lenis({
        duration: 2.5,
        easing: (t) => Math.min(1, 1.001 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t))  
      })
      
      
      function raf(time) {
        lenis.raf(time)
        requestAnimationFrame(raf)
      }
      
      requestAnimationFrame(raf)

}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my workaround.

`page/_app.tsx`: Pass the Lenis instance via Context API.

```js
import { createContext, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Lenis from '@studio-freight/lenis'

export const AppContext = createContext<{
  lenis: Lenis | null
} | null>(null)

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [lenis, setLenis] = useState<Lenis | null>(null)

  const raf = useCallback(
    (time: number) => {
      lenis?.raf(time)
      requestAnimationFrame(raf)
    },
    [lenis]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!lenis) {
      setLenis(new Lenis())
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(raf)

    return () => {
      lenis?.destroy()
    }
  }, [lenis, raf])

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ lenis }}>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

`components/Link.tsx`: Create a link component that scrolls Lenis to the top on route change.

```js
import Router from 'next/router'
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from 'next/link'
import { AnchorHTMLAttributes, memo, useContext } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from '../pages/_app'

const Link = memo(
  (props: LinkProps & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
    const lenis = useContext(AppContext)?.lenis

    return (
      <NextLink
        {...props}
        onClick={(e) => {
          if (
            (!props.target || props.target === '_slef') &&
            props.scroll !== false
          ) {
            e.preventDefault()
            Router.push(props.href).then(() => {
              lenis?.scrollTo(0, {
                immediate: true,
              })
            })
          }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
)

export default Link
```

`page/index.tsx`: Use your link component instead of `next/link`

```js
import Link from '../components/Link'

// ...

<Link href="/about/">About</Link>

// ...
```